# Examples of login landing pages handling many logins

Tags: login

Trying to figure out an effective design pattern for handling multiple logins options.

Users right now land on a page with 5 login options, each takes the user to a dedicated login service. Essentially the first page is a login hub.

One route on the table, is a dropdown selector "I want to login into ____"

Comment: What if user wants to switch from one login service to other after successful login

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, make sure you say **"sign in *with*"**. I realize that you are signing in to that other service and then round-tripping, but that's how users want to think of it. Especially if they're already signed into that service in another tab. Just a perceptual thing.

Comment: If users want to login into a different service, they revisit the page. Each login is it's own site/platform at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty like the login hub from Podio (https://podio.com/signup?force_locale=en_US), with 4 different options.

The best thing about their login is, that they are providing **one main sign up** and three further options. There are different kinds of customers and there is especially one group which needs your attention. People who don't like to take decisions, they would just like to go straight ahead. So provide the most important login as a "main login suggestion".

Comment: Agreed. Even Stack Exchange does it. I wish websites would just list the original login method first without having to click a button that says 'Login with your [OUR WEBSITE] account'. It hurts for those of us that aren't lazy and don't want to connect all our social accounts to **every** site we visit...

Comment: The podio site isn't great, the focus is very heavy on their own login system and the other providers are placed in a way that visually suggest they're social media. As in "tweet about our login page". 

A design like (http://w3layouts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/facebook-twitter-google-login.jpg) still offers up the own login as default, but shows FB/google/twitter as equally valid options.

Comment: @PixelSnader thanks for this, that's an better example then Podio :)

Answer (score -1):

I find most log-in page irritable, especially when I'm accessing the page from a mobile device. The real estate gets clogged by multiple options. A drop-down is an option, but I would advise against it as it's seldom used in login pages. You could consider icon buttons instead, following a default option with a  button like in the examples I've listed below.

**The objective of a login page is to allow the user to authenticate them into the application**. The **method / order of login service is irrelevant** as long as it's a relevant way to get the user into the application. i.e. **No one would use their LinkedIn account to log into a Pornography site**; that's common sense anyway... and this common sense could help you determine which service/option is the default and other stacking details.

Here are some examples that I've liked. I'm using both mobile and desktop screenshots here. As you would notice, the real estate spent to provide login options is very little across devices. I also found [this post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/design-of-login-with-multiple-options) which may be helpful to you.

**Airbnb**

[image]

**Issuu**

[image]

**Pintrest**

[image]

and **Best Desktop login (with too many options): StackExchange!**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]